# What is the entropy change of a hatching egg?

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy

Treating the whole egg as the system.

On one hand: The egg *was* only one cell, but when it becomes a full-grown chicken, it becomes a large number of cells, highly specialized to do their own jobs. So the system becomes more ordered. Thus, $\mathrm{d}S<0$.

However, when we hatch the egg, we have to keep it at a certain temperature, so that the egg can absorb heat from the outside world, or $\mathrm{d}H>0$. If $\mathrm{d}S<0$, we get $\mathrm{d}G=\mathrm{d}H-T\mathrm{d}S>0$, which should not be possible.

I'm just getting started with thermodynamics, so I want to know what did I do wrong here.

Comment: I don't agree with the premise that the egg must be kept warm to absorb heat from the surroundings. An alternate explanation is that the egg must be kept warm to enable kinetic processes to run at the appropriate speed such that the cells stay alive to output metabolic heat. Perhaps you could clarify with references.

Comment: Any entropy changes during development occurred using energy inputs from the egg. The chick requires energy to break the egg. You have not clearly defined your processes.

Comment: @Chemomechanics That's a great perspective! You are right in that cells do create a lot of heat when they undergo metabolism. But I'm still wondering whether the egg's hatching actually requires energy input from the outside.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thermodynamic entropy has nothing to do with purposefulness or number of cells. A million introductions to entropy notwithstanding, it's also only correlated to even well-defined "orderliness" in systems in which we can pretend that the only energy in the system is the energy associated with thermal motion - a pretty good approximation for a heat engine, but a really bad approximation for most of the universe, which is full of dissipative processes. A dissipative process is a process that increases total system entropy faster than total system entropy would increase in the absence of the process, while at the same time making *part* of the system have less entropy than it would otherwise have. A system with dissipative processes (note again: defined by increasing in entropy faster) is *self-ordering* - giving the lie to the idea that order and entropy are necessarily opposites.

If you want to apply the 2nd Law to systems that include things other than heat sources, heat sumps, and the gasses and idealized rigid walls of heat engines, I think it's easiest to define entropy in terms of the change of [Gibbs free energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibbs_free_energy). This works well for anything from galactic superclusters to eggs. The egg is quietly dissipating chemical potential energy and in the process turning egg chemicals into chicken chemicals - some of which chicken chemicals will in turn have their own chemical potential energy dissipated and in the process turn stationary chicken parts into moving chicken parts capable of breaking out of the shell.

Comment: I've actually read about a question elsewhere: which is higher in entropy: a crystal at absolute zero or a DNA strand at room temp? From the thermodynamics perspective, the crystal at 0K obviously is lower. But DNA is more "ordered" in that it has more information, or lower in "information entropy". So the mistake I made is trying to do a faulty generalization of the traditional "heat entropy" into something that might not be accurately described in the thermodynamics world. Is that correct?

Comment: Information entropy isn't the same quantity as thermodynamic entropy. Also, having more information isn't the same as having less information entropy; generally the opposite is the case. Two similar signals have twice the information and twice the information entropy, much as two similar rocks have twice the energy and twice the thermodynamic entropy.

Comment: "A dissipative process is a process that increases total system entropy faster than total system entropy would increase in the absence of the process" this is true only if a nondissipative process can also exist with the same starting and end points and still views entropy per the conventional Clausius formula , ie integrating the $\delta Q_{rev}/T$.